# Displaying DIVs inline with jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I display multiple DIVs with same class and different IDs inline with jQuery? I.e.
first I want to check if DIV exists in BODY and then show the next DIV after the current DIV.

Comment: This needs some more explanation.

Comment: "check if div exists in body than show the next div after the current div" this statement is confusing, at least to me.

Comment: i want to show divs inline just like facebook chat

Comment: I think you need to rephrase. None of the div elements in facebook chat are inline.

Comment: bros i want to create and display my divs one after other with jquery. 
i am referencing facebook chat boxs placement not inline........i.e how can i place and create new divs one after other......!!

Comment: Use `float:left` - seems like what you are asking... otherwise it's an obscure answer for an obscure question :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('div.className').each(function(i,elem){
    elem.style.display = 'inline';
  });
```

Doesn't matter if the DIV with the class exist, the loop with exit if none matches.

Comment: What's wrong with `$('div.className').css('display', 'inline');` ?

Answer (score 2):

A better version is:

```
$("div.className").css("display", "inline");
```

Comment: Yes, I agree this is a better version too. +1